# SQL - Repeated sum of the values, based on dates selected

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Currently, I need a simple thing:

| sale_date | Gross | SUM_GROSS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | 1 | 6 |
| 2018-01-02 | 2 | 6 |
| 2018-01-03 | 3 | 6 |

I know this question already mentioned before, the difference now, is that I need to calculate a sum based on selected dates. (I use BigQuery)

```
SUM(SALES.GrossValueBaseCurrency) OVER(PARTITION BY ???) AS SUM_GROSS
```

If I will use

```
SUM(SALES.GrossValueBaseCurrency) OVER(PARTITION BY SALE.SALE_DATE) AS SUM_GROSS
```

It will give me what I would like ONLY if I will select specific ONE day.

How can I make it work, so if I will select different dates,  `SUM_GROSS` will repeat the SUM of ALL gross values for a selected period of time?

**SAMPLE DATA and Expectations:**

Expecting 60 in **SUM_GROSS** column

```
Row SALE_DATE   GROSS   SUM_GROSS
1   25/08/2018  10.00   60
2   04/10/2018  10.00   60
3   04/07/2018  10.00   60
4   01/03/2018  10.00   60
5   10/02/2018  10.00   60
6   10/01/2018  10.00   60
```

If you will query this table result should be :

```
SELECT SUM(GROSS) AS GROSS, SUM_GROSS FROM TABLE
WHERE SALE_DATE BETWEEN 01/01/2018 AND 01/04/2018
GROUP BY SUM_GROSS
```

RESULT:

```
GROSS   SUM_GROSS
30      30
```

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Have update my question

Comment: @GordonLinoff Have add query and output based on initial table

Comment: @GordonLinoff Do you think it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want conversation in `partition` clause:

```
SUM(SALES.GrossValueBaseCurrency) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR from SALE.SALE_DATE), EXTRACT(MONTH from SALE.SALE_DATE)) AS SUM_GROSS
```

EDIT :

```
SELECT . . .,
       SUM(SALES.GrossValueBaseCurrency) OVER () AS SUM_GROSS 
FROM SALES s
WHERE SALE.SALE_DATE BETWEEN "2018-01-01 AND "2018-02-01"
```

Comment: The output does not match, sorry for my knowledge limitation, I understand the principle of partitioning, but this senction do not get it... `EXTRACT(YEAR from SALE.SALE_DATE), EXTRACT(MONTH from SALE.SALE_DATE)`

Comment: In addition, if I will add EXTRACT(DAY from SALE.SALE_DATE) it will show me the sum of the gross per day (not grouped in). but I need SUM per selected period which will be repeated in each row. Like I show in my first table

Comment: Have added, sample data, query and output... please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SUM(CASE WHEN sales.sale_date = '2018-01-01'
         THEN SALES.GrossValueBaseCurrency
         ELSE 0
    END) OVER () AS sales_20180101
```

Comment: This will give me the sum for ONE day only, BUT I need to make if for for selected period. Like `WHERE SALE.SALE_DATE BETWEEN "2018-01-01 AND "2018-02-01"` in SUM_GROSS it will repeat the sum of the gross for a month... if select different dates, will display different SUM_GROSS

Comment: You can put any range you want in the `WHEN` condition.

Comment: That's true, let's try to make it another way, it should be a view, by calling which and changing the date in `WHERE` it will display `SUM_GROSS` based on this criteria. I can explain in a more detailed way, but it is a tricky question (which looks really easy initially) - it should be similar to the way Yogesh Sharma answered.

Comment: For example - `SUM(SALES.GrossValueBaseCurrency) OVER() AS SUM_GROSS` with giving a sum of gross from the whole database, it does not count date period. but it works as I need (except dates)